# How do I change the like and reblog button colors with this code?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

Trying to change tumblr like and reblog button colors, the only code I found related to them is this. Adding in "color: #;" didn't change anything. What would I need to write for the colors to change?

```
<pre>
.reblog_button,
.like_button iframe {
    width: {text:Font Size} !important; /* calc fallback */
    height: {text:Font Size} !important; /* calc fallback */
    width: calc({text:Font Size} + 2px) !important;
    height: calc({text:Font Size} + 2px) !important;
</pre>
```

Apologies if this is a stupid question, started learning HTML very recently, still a beginner.

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish the same.
1. first you might create 2 different images one is plain white color and the remaining is the desired colored image. when your mouse over on the image you should replace the image with a colored image. And when mouseout you should replace the original white image.

Comment: 2nd way is to use a transparent SVG image and fill the white color as the default color and when mouse over you should update CSS. Please follow the below links:
https://css-tricks.com/the-many-ways-to-change-an-svg-fill-on-hover-and-when-to-use-them/#:~:text=icon%20class%20in%20CSS%20and,hover%20state%20to%20swap%20colors.&text=This%20is%20by%20far%20the,or%20as%20a%20background%20image.